Custom ssh port configuration will listen only on IPv6 of the system
After today's update of openssh-server (1:9.6p1-3ubuntu13.5 ⇒ 1:9.6p1-3ubuntu13.7) any custom port definition on systemctl edit ssh.socket configuration like this will not cause ssh.socket to listen on the IPv4 of the system:
ListenStream=2222

init will listen only on the IPv6 of the system.

One solution is to put two lines like these
when editing with the systemctl edit ssh.socket command:
[Socket]
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:2222
ListenStream=[::]:2222

and run
# systemctl restart ssh.socket

The cause of this change is the addition of
BindIPv6Only=ipv6-only

to the default configuration at /usr/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket.

Unfortunately our VPN requires IPv4, so this sudden change breaks a bunch of stuff.
I made the changes you suggested above.  That doesn't work, we get an error when trying to restart ssh.socket or sshd.service.  Rebooting after editing doesn't help.  Nor does leaving the ipv6 configuration out of the above.

I don't understand why I can't just edit sshd_config and restart the ssh service.

@rotten What is the version of your Ubuntu? Are you using 24.04 or above? What is the version in systemctl --version? What is the output of systemctl status ssh.socket? Please, post a new question if your configuration is different.

Yes, 24.04.1 with systemd systemd 255 (255.4-1ubuntu8.4) +PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT -GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY +P11KIT +QRENCODE +TPM2 +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -BPF_FRAMEWORK -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified  ...  I was eventually able to get it to work by updating sshd_config and doing service ssh restart.  I'm not sure it will survive another reboot, will try soon.

The sshd_config update was to set ListenAddress 0.0.0.0 and leave the IPv6 one commented out.  I also left AddressFamily commented out.

On restart, sshd refuses to start because it thinks something is already listening to the port.  Nothing is listening on that port according to netstat.  I can get it to go by fussing with ssh.socket and the ports that sshd_config is listening to, but it is really confusing and needlessly complicated.
